# How to fix this Rg.Plugins.Popup bug?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, crash

We're using the Rg.Plugins.Popup on our project. There is a crash in our app being caused by a Rg.Plugins.Popup exception. That crash occurs on iOS Version.

The only thing we've got is the following stacktrace:

```
Rg.Plugins.Popup.IOS.Renderers.PopupPageRenderer.UpdateElementSize()
Rg.Plugins.Popup.IOS.Renderers.PopupPageRenderer.ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
ObjCRuntime.Messaging.objc_msgSend(intptr, intptr)(wrapper managed-to-native)
CoreAnimation.CATransaction.Commit()
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.CADisplayLinkTicker.StartThread()
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

That exception occurs in the last stable plugin version: 1.0.4 and the last pre-release version 5.

So, anyone has a basic idea of what is that and how to eliminate the exception?

Comment: It's [open source](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup). I haven't tried it on iOS platform, but some behaviors became clearer to me when I imported the source code  to a simple context project to debug. Have you tried it?

Comment: When do you hit the error

Comment: Please, create an issues with a stack trace in github and I will try to fix it. Thank you. https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: I created the new issue, thanks. https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/210